Where should I store my model if I want it loaded while running my application on Magic Leap?
I need my GGML model loaded when I open my app. But I used
params.model = "files\\gpt-2-117M";
std::ifstream file(params.model);
if (!file.good()) {
        return "wrong";
    }

It always returns "wrong", which means the file is not opened properly.
if I use: getcwd(path,255); ,the path would be \
I guess the path may be wrong. Where should I store my model on Magic Leap?
I expect to run samples of GGML GPT-2 on Magic Leap 2.
